# Loading jpg image over mat frame opencv java

Tags: java, opencv

I have hand detection code right now that creates a green rectangle around the hand when detected. However, I want to fill the rectangle with another jpeg image. I was thinking of using [ImagePattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html) where the image gets embedded inside the shape however that did not seem to work in my program.

Here is my code for creating the rectangle around the hand :

```
Imgproc.rectangle(frame, handsArray[i].tl(), handsArray[i].br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
```

The frame is a Mat and Imgproc is a opencv, javacv function.

Can someone please help me with this problem? I am struggling

Regards

[Green Rectangle Around The Hand that needs to be filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgIWz.jpg)

```
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    try {
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File(trollFace));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    mat.put(0, 0, data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in these steps:

1. Submat the rectangle from your source image

   Mat submat = src.submat(new Rect(200, 200, 100, 100));
2. Now copy the sencond image into the submat

   src2.copyTo(submat);

**Note:** Before copying, insure the size of the second image is the same as the rectangle, if not you can use the `resize()` function of the `Imgprc` class to resize the Mat. And it is that.

**Update:** The below is the example.

```
Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\src1.jpg");
Mat src2 = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\src2.jpg");
Imgproc.resize(src2, src2, new Size(100, 100));
Mat submat = src.submat(new Rect(200, 200, 100, 100));
src2.copyTo(submat);

// now you can do what you want with the src1
```

Comment: I tried to implement what you said. First I converted the jpg to a bufferedImage and then to a mat (because source image 'frame' is a mat). So src was frame and src2 was the converted bufferImage. I don't know what I am doing wrong but the image is still not getting displayed. Please scroll up to see how I made Mat src2

Comment: You do not need to use Java ImageIO to read the image file, you can use the OpenCV `Imgcodecs` class for reading and writing image. The question updated you have a look now. Note that all the image format in OpenCV must be Mat object, BufferedImage is not the OpenCV data type.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am gonna experiment and read more about this so that I can make the loaded of the picture's background transparent

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer has solved your question, then please accept and vote up the answer to mark the question as solved to help if anyone else has the same problem in the feature. Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thanks again!

Comment: There are a lot of good functions and algorithms in the OpenCV library to process the image, you can look the OpenCV API and tutorials, and also it is easy to learn, all the useful and basic functions can be found in the Core and Imgproc classes. Good Luck!

Comment: Hey I know stackoverflow does not work this way but I am trying to change the background of the rect mask. What is happening is when I run the code, the png file has a transparent background however when it is inside the rect mask, the background changes to black [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNXtl.png) so I started to look into alpha channels but to be quite honest I am lost. Is there a tutorial to make the image transparent?

Comment: You can try this http://answers.opencv.org/question/37441/how-to-set-transparent-background-to-grabcut-output-image-in-opencv-c/